# How can I use GnuPG with ECDSA keys?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, cryptography, public-key-encryption, ecc

I'd like to generate an ECDSA (rather than RSA, DSA, or ElGamal) key using GnuPG, and use it as I might otherwise use an OpenPGP-compatible master key. I've [read](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-devel/2010-September/025731.html) that `gpg2`has support for ECDSA keys, but I haven't been able to use that functionality. What am I missing?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34567/ecc-in-openpgp is related, no?

Answer (score 6):

GnuPG 2.1.x does support ECC (including Ed25519); for more info (and examples), see https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html#ecc.

FYI, you must add the `--expert` option to reveal the new options.

Answer (score 1):

Neither GPG 1.4.x nor GPG 2.0.x currently support ECC or ECDSA keys.  Werner has been working on it for the highly developmental 2.1.x releases, but that's nowhere near ready for production use.  Elliptic Curve may be backported to the current stable releases in the future, but there is no timeframe on that.

Comment: support for this is now in the `modern` branch. So this is *somewhat more near* stable. https://www.gnupg.org/download/

Comment: This answer is out of date and should be updated or removed.